# Dart shelf server: only apply middleware to selected routes

Tags: dart, dart-shelf, dart-server, shelf-router

In Dart shelf_router, I can add middleware like so:

```
final handler = Pipeline()
    .addMiddleware(logRequests())
    .addMiddleware(auth())
    .addHandler(router.call);
```

However, I want the `auth` middleware to only apply to certain routes, not all of them:

```
final router = Router()
  ..get('/public', _publicHandler)    // no auth
  ..get('/private', _privateHandler); // this route should apply auth
```

How would I do that?

Comment: I guess I could add a route whitelist to `auth` but I was wondering if there was a built in way to do it.